# Assigning Action to a custom Button and UI layout issue

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I ran into two issues while working on the UI of the form:

1. I created an Action but I can't seem to assign it to the new button that I've created. It appeared on toolbar instead as highlighted in red box
   [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyOzK.png). The code on the Action and Button:

   ```
    public PXAction<CashAccount> RefreshAvailability;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select, Enabled = true)]

    protected virtual void refreshLCAvailability()
    {
        //logic here
    }
   ```
2. I inserted two Column controls to separate the fields into two columns as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zicn5.png) but the output is not like what I wanted it to be as shown in the image in point 1.

I feel like I'm missing something very simple but can't seem to figure what.

Edit:

The first issue has been solved by assigning the Command as well as the Target as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Yvsx.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the second issue by trial and error. So basically, you need to:

1. Insert an Empty Layout control after Merge control
2. Specify the Merge property as False

[Image for point 1 & 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu0TN.png)

3. Insert another Column in between the two
4. Insert a Label control in the newly created Column
5. Leave the Label Text as blank

[Image for point 3, 4 & 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0n7Bv.png)

It is mind boggling that I have to do it in this roundabout way. If there is any better way of doing this, please do share it in this thread.